# how to split jq output at every json object

Tags: java, spring, bash, curl, jq

```
{
  "title": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "languageKey": "ja"
}    {
  "title": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "languageKey": "ja"
}    {
  "title": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "languageKey": "ja"
}
```

This output is fed to a curl request

ref: https://www.elastic.co/blog/loading-wikipedia

```
curl localhost:9200/dewikiquote/_search -d '{"query": {"match_all":{}}}' \
| jq '.hits.hits[] | ._source' \
| jq '{title: .heading[0], description: .text, languageKey: "ja"} \
| curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -XPUT 'http://localhost:11223/context/api/add' -d @-
```

But below java endpoint is hit only once and the map `data` has only one title, description and languagekey. Why are the other json items lost?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/add", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void add(@RequestBody Map<String, String> data)
{ 
...
```

Is that because the jq output is not split at every json object? if yes how do I do that with jq?

Comment: so lemme get this cleared, u are requesting something from ElasticSearch then trying to feed its output  into another curl which talks to a java implemented server right?

Comment: yes I am trying to implement elastic search type functionality with hibernate search + lucene. I wanted to get the wikiquote data to test my custom analyzers.

Comment: the way I see it , by the time you are trying to send it to the end point, the data is not an array anymore, can't say 100% but @zeeshan answer might work, if not, you may want to consider do some looping on the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative, which loops through the results and send each individually:

Please Note the `-c` to print each output without indent.

```
curl localhost:9200/dewikiquote/_search -d '{"query": {"match_all":{}}}' \
| jq '.hits.hits[] | ._source' \
| jq -c '{title: .heading[0], description: .text, languageKey: "ja"} \
| while read next; do curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -XPUT 'http://localhost:11223/context/api/add' -d $next; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try like this:

```
curl localhost:9200/dewikiquote/_search -d '{"query": {"match_all":{}}}' \
| jq '.[] | {title: .title, description: .description, languageKey: "ja"} \
| curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -XPUT 'http://localhost:11223/context/api/add' -d @-
```

you are missing the '.[]' array operation operator on the returned json list